# Is the cannizaro reaction possible for a molecule having hydrogens attached to sp2 hybridised carbons?

Tags: carbonyl-compounds

As known benzaldehyde can undergo a cannizaro reaction in which a phenyl group is an electron donating group, so the reaction similar to below  (of prop-2-enal) (cannizaro) should occur for similar molecule 'either having all hydrogen connected to SP2 hybridised carbon (eg: pent2,4dienal) or the carbon which is SP3 hybridized connected to double bond should not have any hydrogen connected to it (eg: 4,4,4triimethylbutanaldehyde)' should show cannizaro.

Major product in basic medium should be decided by the below reaction (Cannizaro Reaction) and not aldol condensation. Am I correct?

[image: Cannizaro Reaction]

I don't think that acid base reaction can occur with concentrated base in this case.

This may be helpful
Bond energy of $\ce{C-H}$ bond in methane $\pu{415 kJ/mole}$.

Bond energy of $\ce{C-H}$ bond in ethene $\pu{444 kJ/mole}$.

Comment: Your question isn't about "hydrogens next to sp2 carbons": benzaldehyde has $\ce{C_\mathrm{sp^2}-H}$ bonds as well, but you *already* know what's going on with benzaldehydes. Your question is really about **α,β-unsaturated aldehydes**, isn't it?

Comment: @orthocresol Yes. I have tried to express my thoughts in question as much as I can and I am sorry because I didn't know acrolien will undergo hazardous reaction (and wasted much time of community) and will not represent my doubt clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to The Hazardous Substances Databank entry for acrolein  [here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/source/hsdb/177#section=Hazardous-Reactivities-and-Incompatibilities)

> An extremely violent polymerization reaction of acrolein results from contact with alkaline materials such as sodium hydroxide, potassium hydroxide, ammonia and amines. Mixing sodium hydroxide and acrolein in a closed container caused the temperature and pressure to increase.

The next compound in the series, crotonaldehyde, certainly also polymerises in alkaline conditions. I am inclined to think this is general. There are just too many other pathways available for these reactive molecules under the strongly basic conditions of Cannizaro, not least retro-aldol.

Comment: I think the retro aldol is the more likely outcome of creating the enolate. You then have pivalaldehyde plus acetaldehyde. Pivaldehyde gives Cannizzaro but acetaldehyde will react all over the place.